# ¿Cómo puedo descargar y transformar en PDF una página web desde ASP.NET con C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, pdf

Les explico mi problema, pasa que intento descargar un PDF de [esta página](http://dof.gob.mx/nota_detalle.php?codigo=5480876&fecha=27/04/2017&print.html&print=true) para ser específico.

```
public static void DescargarPDF()
{
    string Link = @"http://dof.gob.mx/nota_detalle.php?codigo=5480876&fecha=27/04/2017&print=true";
    string RutaArchivo = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Docs/Prueba.pdf");
    using (WebClient oWebClient = new WebClient())
    {
        oWebClient.DownloadFile(Link, RutaArchivo);
    }
}
```

Pero al abrir el PDF, me aparece:

> Adobe Reader no pudo abrir "Prueba.pdf" debido a que no es un tipo de archivo admitido o está dañado.

Lo raro es que al abrir el link directamente en Chrome se genera un PDF que al parecer es por un *script* que Chrome genera automáticamente, en Firefox por ejemplo solo me deja imprimir.

¿De qué otra manera puedo descargarlo en PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que logro notar, no se trata meramente de un PDF, es un HTML que internamente hacen la conversión y se manda llamar al servicio de impresión en PDF.

Lo que puedes hacer es obtener el HTML de la petición y a su vez utilizar alguna librería para convertir ese HTML a PDF, por ejemplo, [`PdfSharp`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp/), para lo cual, quedaría algo así:

```
public static Byte[] DescargarPDF()
{
    Byte[] resultado = null;

    string Link = @"http://dof.gob.mx/nota_detalle.php?codigo=5480876&fecha=27/04/2017&print=true";
    string RutaArchivo = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Docs/Prueba.txt");
    using (WebClient oWebClient = new WebClient())
    {
        oWebClient.DownloadFile(Link, RutaArchivo);
    }

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(File.ReadAllText(@"~\Docs\Prueba.txt"), PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
        pdf.Save(memoryStream);
        res = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

De igual forma, existen otras alternativas como [`iTextSharp`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/), o [`Winnovative`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/wnvhtmlconvert/).

Comment: Gracias, de hecho ocupo iTextSharp para sacar información, pero mejor adapte el algoritmo para sacarlo directamente del html. Saludos.